# Video Splitter for MPG

Tags: windows-7, video, software-rec, mpeg

I need a good video splitter, for .avi and .mpg.

I already know about Easy Video Splitter, but it doesn't work with .mpg.
OS is Win 7.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a 'video splitter'? The answers below seem adequate but you don't seem happy with the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) to split .mpg and .avi videos.

[Here](http://www.my-guides.net/en/guides/general-video/99-how-to-cutsplitmergeeffectaudio-video-files-using-virtualdub) is a nice guide to how to do it.

[image: caps]

Here is an unofficial [MPEG-2 upgrade](http://home.comcast.net/~fcchandler/Plugins/MPEG2/) for making VirtualDub support MPEG-1 and MPEG-2 program streams.

Comment: Video files I want to split are those recorded with DVB-T from TV. So, when I try to load that kind of file with VirtualDub, I get the message "MPEG Import Filter: invalid pack at position position 3: marker bit not set; possibly MPEG-2 stream". Is it possible that these files cannot be splitted?

Comment: @MladenB: There is an [unofficial MPEG-2 upgrade](http://home.comcast.net/~fcchandler/Plugins/MPEG2/) for VirtualDub but I didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good success with TMPGenc, a free tool available here:
http://www.tmpgenc.net/en/download.html

Details on how to split and join MPG and AVI are here:
http://www.wikihow.com/Split-Audio-off-a-Video-File-using-TMPGENC

Comment: I want to split video file in order to make few smaller parts, not to split audio off a video file.

Answer (score 0):

Some good and free video editors :

[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)
[Lightworks](http://www.lightworksbeta.com/)
[VideoLAN Movie Creator (VLMC)](http://trac.videolan.org/vlmc/)
[LiVES Video Editing System](http://lives.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one'

http://download.cnet.com/AVI-MPEG-RM-WMV-Splitter/3000-13631_4-10192961.html

Comment: Free to try (10-day trial); $34.95 to buy